# `gc.get_objects()` not getting all object?

Tags: python, numpy, garbage-collection

I was trying to let `numpy` show all arrays exist in the memory (`np.who()` by default only shows arrays that are globally defined). I did some experiment with `gc.get_objects()` but found it did not return all objects that I was expecting. Here's what i have done:

```py
In [1]: a = [[object()]]

In [2]: import gc

In [3]: for i in gc.get_objects():
   ...:     if i is a:
   ...:         print('found a')
   ...:     elif i is a[0]:
   ...:         print('found a[0]')
   ...:     elif i is a[0][0]:
   ...:         print('found the object')
   ...:
found a
found a[0]

In [4]: import numpy as np

In [5]: a = [[np.empty(4)]]

In [6]: for i in gc.get_objects():
   ...:     if i is a:
   ...:         print('found a')
   ...:     elif i is a[0]:
   ...:         print('found a[0]')
   ...:     elif isinstance(i, np.ndarray):
   ...:         print(f'found array with shape {i.shape} and dtype {i.dtype}')
   ...:
   ...:
found array with shape () and dtype float64
found array with shape () and dtype float64
found a
found a[0]
```

For the first case, the `object()` is never found. For the second case, the array with shape `(4,)` (instead of `()`) is not found. I'm wondering is my understanding of `gc.get_objects()` wrong? It says

> Return a list of objects tracked by the collector (excluding the list returned)

Does that mean those numpy arrays won't be deleted automatically by gc?

Comment: There's an important qualifier you've overlooked: "Return a list of objects **tracked by the collector** (excluding the list returned)"

Comment: Other objects are handled purely by reference counting.

Comment: @user2357112 So "tracked objects" means objects that are involved in some reference cycle?

Comment: No. Tracked objects are objects the cyclic GC keeps track of. These include *most* objects that *have the capability* of participating in a reference cycle, and excludes most objects that do not have such a capability.